# Readiness for Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud Data Flow's documentation describes how to integrate with kubernetes Readiness probes.  I'm developing my dataflow locally and running it in a docker-compose configuration, while we wait for our k8s SCDF environment to be stood up.

Is there another way to implement a readiness / do not send data context for SCDF?  Upon component spin-up, I need to make a RESTful call and then run some computations on the results.  Things attempted unsuccessfully:

- use of ApplicationAvailabilityEvents - publishing a ReadinessState.ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC after the load + compilation is complete, after publishing a ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC.  When Spring completes its own load, it publishes an ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC, and so doesn't wait for mine from my service.
- setting up an ApplicationRunner which also serves as an ApplicationListener for custom events which I throw when the computations are complete.  Effectively, the run() method looks like:

```
public class ApplicationStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner, ApplicationListener {

private boolean sessionLoaded = false;

public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

  doTimeExpensiveThing();

  while (!sessionLoaded) {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150);
  }
}

public void onApplicationEvent(SessionLoadEvent event) {

  this.sessionLoaded = true;

}
}
```

Additional technical note: the Spring Boot application is built as a processor, which is using a function exposed as a Bean to provide its capability, ala
`public Function<Flux<ChangeEvent>, Flux<Alert>> processChangeEvents()`

Optimally, whatever approach I use which works in docker-compose, I'll wire into an indicator which'll be picked up by k8s and its readiness probe.  Given that SCDF can be deployed on k8s, docker-compose (locally), or CloudFoundry, hoping that there's a model I can hook into that I've just overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer: instead of using the ApplicationRunner, wait in the processChangeEvents method and do not return the function until startup processing is complete.

In our case, because the doTimeExpensiveThing is an asynchronous activity, I use the technique of watching/waiting for the sessionLoaded flag, but now within the processChangeEvents method itself.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationForProcessor implements ApplicationEventListener<SessionLoadEvent> {

  boolean sessionLoaded;

  Function<Flux<ChangeEvent>, Flux<Alert>> processChangeEvents() {
    
    doTimeExpensiveAsynchronousThing();

    while (!sessionLoaded) {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(150);
    }

    return (Flux<ChangeEvent>) -> ... code which returns a Flux of Alert
  }

  public void onApplicationEvent(SessionLoadEvent event) {
    this.sessionLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Very open to guidance on other approaches.  This appears like it's working, though not sure there aren't gotchas I haven't caught yet.